# gxt-all.css for gxt 2.3.1a

Tags: extjs, gxt

I upgraded from GXT 2.2 to 2.3.1a to prep for an upgrade to 3.x (it's gonna be painfull). Looks like there is a bug in MenuItem which can be fixed by overridding a method in MenuItem or the gxt-all.css for 2.3.1a. (search for: migration-to-gxt2.3.1-grid-header-menu-no-longer-displays-properly. on the Sencha Forum; sorry, troubles getting a link to work here :(

Anybody have a link to a site where I can download this (and whatever else I need). All I got are the distributed JAR files. Thanx. ~r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.3.1 is only available for support subscribers.
You can download 2.3.0 here:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.3.0.zip

Although, your problem seems to be fixable only by overwriting the MenuItem class, like this:

Overwrite the onRender()-Method in com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.menu.MenuItem.java and change 
setElement(DOM.createSpan(), target, index); 
to 
setElement(DOM.createAnchor(), target, index);

Comment: and that zip file appears to be corrupt >:-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of the GXT background... but it appears it was bought by Sencha a few years ago and now you pay for the GXT framework. Point being is that legality of its use should be reviewed.

That being said, an alternative solution to your problem would be to style the MenuItem or add a styled wrapper class. Adjusting the padding on the MenuItem should give you the look you are accustom to.  The GXT 2.3.1 showcase can be reviewed [here](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#basictoolbar) and using a web development tool like Firebug you can get a better understanding of what kind of CSS rules were used to style the MenuItem in 2.3.1.